# App Center missing icons on Loki

Tags: release-loki, updates, icons, appcenter

I recently installed Elementary OS 0.4, after doing some regular installations and updates, the *App Center* (0.1.3) icons are missing, they have a gray gear instead. How can I fix this?

[image: This is how it looks]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a problem on your end.  I have the same issue and i am sure they are working on this and hopefully an update will hit soon to fix.  Apps should still download and install with no problem.  You may want to read the description carefully as there are no icons to know exactly what you are downloading.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It appears to be they fixed it today.

Comment: I am still having the same problem with mine

Comment: i still have the same problem i have been having.

Comment: Quite weird, because the only thing that I remember that I did, was updating the system, a regular apt-get update. I was able to see that it downloaded some kind of icons.

Comment: Still having the same problem.