# Missing Icons in AppCenter - Juno

Tags: appcenter, release-juno, icons

I'm missing 4 icons in AppCenter.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

All the other application icons are displayed.

It looks like there was a similar issue in Loki...

[App Center missing icons on Loki](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10444/app-center-missing-icons-on-loki)

..but that looks like it was missing all icons, not just a select few.

Is there a way for me to fix this or is this something for the developers to look at?

Anybody else experiencing this issue? Are they the same missing icons or different ones?

Comment: I had the same problem right after installing. I had no internet and it didn't update the icons. Then i setup my internet connection, updated and everything went back to normal.

Comment: I have updated my system, but still have those 4 missing icons.  The icons show up in the Application Menu, they just don't show up in AppCenter.

Comment: What is the language in your system?

Comment: The language is English.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and am missing the same icons on a fully updated Juno. Has there been any solution that worked for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Install App-editor and in each one of those apps, try to search for the icon (in available icons, not manually). This way you can see if the icons are installed in the system. If the icon is available, select it and save each time. That should solve it.

Comment: The icons are installed. They show up in Slingshot/Application Menu. They also show up in AppEditor.  In AppEditor, it doesn't give me the option to save - probably because I'm choosing the exact same icon that it's already using. The icons show up everywhere except AppCenter.

Comment: Change to other icons, save and then change it back and save them again.
Weird bug :)

Comment: I tried changing to a new icon. It changes the icon in Slingshot/Application Menu. I changed it back to its own icon.  Again, it changes it in the Application Menu. Nothing gets changed in AppCenter.   Yeah, it's weird.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change a icon with AppEdit, you will need to work  it with administrator rights or you can change with this command sudo "a file editor like vi" /usr/share/applications/org."filename".desktop