# failed to fetch updates without solution

Tags: updates, release-juno

i know that this is a well known trouble in community, but i sure that i already read all off and tried a lot of things, like sudo upgrade and edit text files, but i'm here because i realy love Eos, i use since march and this is the first bug in the system and i don't want leave the os because a little thing like this.
(using juno)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at your first screenshot, you're experiencing the same issue that I am: Missing icons in AppCenter - https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16975/missing-icons-in-appcenter-juno

Comment: i have all the items and programs working normally, but i can't update since a month ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First

There's no way you could have that repository in `juno` because that repository doesn't have a release for `bionic`

They don't even have one for `loki` (`xenial`), they stopped at `freya` (`trusty`)

Just remove the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:elementaryos-fr-community/ppa
```

https://launchpad.net/~elementaryos-fr-community/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

---

### Second

You never had problems upgrading, when you updated just that repo was disabled. It clearly says that at the end in the error message